# FTP upload files from subfolders

Tags: c#, ftp

I have problem with  FTP upload files from subfolders.

How I can resolve this problem.

Comment: What is the problem you havent explained it you just threw code at us

Comment: I have problem it not upload files from subfolders to ftp subfolders

Comment: yes but what problem? what error, which line??

Comment: `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: which line? at the moment theres nothing much to work from other than you dont like what your code is doing, the code almost is irrelevant right now until you can be specific.   Why does the second code chunk make 2 connections, you dont seem to send any data to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have mixed up the two requests now. First carry out one request, then begin the other.
2. You have to open your local file, not the ftpFolder:

   FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFileName);
3. Also, you never execute `request1` in your current version.
4. And finally, why do you look for filename from ftpFolder? Isn't that just the remote name?

Comment: I tryed to create folder to ftp and upload folder files to ftp folder what I created.

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to execute Path.GetFileName(ftpFolder) on your local computer. You have to use Directory.GetFiles(localFolder) to get all the files in your current folder, then you loop over the retrieved names and upload one at a time (with remote name ftpFolder+"/"+localFileName).

Comment: `Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll`

Comment: You have to include more information - at the very least from what line the exception was thrown (from its StackTrace), and this exception may well contain an inner exception with a more specific error message. And you need to show your updated code.

Comment: Read the tips in the Remarks section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx